# jQuery setting css widths for classes, but not updating widths upon jQuery-initiated class change

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not sure there's a quick way to explain what I'm doing, so bear with me on this...

I'm setting up a series of column elements (`li.element`), and, upon clicking any one `li.element`, I want it to expand to a given percentage width and have all other column elements revert to the standard size (basically, an accordion).

The tricky part is, I have a **variable number of columns** to account for, and a **variable width of the parent element** to fill up (based on viewport width).

I've worked out the math to dynamically set both the "collapsed" and the "expanded" column widths with jQuery:

```
var TotalWidthInPixels = $("ul.parent").width();
var PercentageWidthOfExpandedColumn = .50
var TotalColumnCount = $("li.element").length;
var ExpandedColumnWidthInPixels = TotalWidthInPixels * PercentageWidthOfExpandedColumn
var CollapsedColumnWidthInPixels = (TotalWidthInPixels * (1.0 - PercentageWidthOfExpandedColumn)) / (TotalColumnCount - 1);
```

I've used the result to set widths for standard (unclassed) and collapsed (`.collapsed`) columns (`li.element`).

```
$("li.element").css("width", ExpandedColumnWidthInPixels);
$(".collapsed").css("width", CollapsedColumnWidthInPixels);
```

I also have some jQuery to add `.collapsed` to every `li.element` by default, and to remove the `.collapsed` from any given column when it is clicked (while also adding `.collapsed` to every other `li.element`; but I run into this error even when I don't re-add `.collapsed`).

```
//// WHEN A COLLAPSED COLUMN IS CLICKED, COLLAPSE ALL OTHERS, THEN EXPAND IT
$(".collapsed").click(function(){
    $("li.element").addClass("collapsed");
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
});
```

The rest of my stylesheet-set CSS (background color, etc.) works as expected with the class switches, so I can be sure that the `.collapsed` class is, in fact, being added and removed via `click()`... but the jQuery-set CSS widths are not updating.  The columns remain at the value which jQuery originally established when the document was ready.

I've removed all mention of width from the stylesheet-set CSS for the elements in question, so I can be sure jQuery is the only thing driving these style widths.

***Note:** I had this interaction up and running as expected when the expanded and collapsed column widths were explicitly and statically set via stylesheet — even with the classes being updated via jQuery on click.  The only thing that has changed is I'm now setting the widths for my classes dynamically via jQuery.*

***Why are my jQuery-set CSS widths not updating when jQuery updates the corresponding CSS classes?***

Comment: Would help to have a fiddle or sample site.

Comment: I guess I'm hoping the code is irrelevant and there's some inherent problem to updating jQuery-set CSS attributes +/ values via a jQuery-driven class switch that I'm just not aware of... but I'll work on getting a fiddle up for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple times reading this, it looks like maybe you are expecting `$(".collapsed").css("width", CollapsedColumnWidthInPixels);` to actually change the definition of the `collapsed` class.. Is that so? If yes, it doesn't work that way. That line sets the widths of the selected elements, it doesn't change class definitions.

I think maybe you need to `ExpandedColumnWidthInPixels` and `CollapsedColumnWidthInPixels` are saved to the window scope and do this instead:

```
$(".collapsed").click(function(){
    $(this).css("width", ExpandedColumnWidthInPixels);
    $("li.element").css("width", CollapsedColumnWidthInPixels);
});
```

Comment: While not a direct answer to the question, I used this line of thought (circumventing using class switching as a basis for width control, and just setting the widths of affected elements directly) as a basis, and got it up and running as desired — thanks!